# use node-generated grayscale image as texture for particles

Tags: texturing, particles

We can drive particle systems by greyscale images (as textures). Is it possible to use an image what was generated by nodes in blender for this, without saving it as an image and open it as a texture? I didn't find anything about it, I guess no is the answer, it's my last try, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible in 2.8 and greater version. For 2.79 and less there was `texture node editor` which generates textures. These textures *maybe* - i'm not sure - used for particle system.

Comment: thanks, it's just.. sad :)